# WPF Button inside ListView not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very simple question for WPF experts.

I start with XAML the code:

```
<ListView Name="ListViewRunner" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentPrices}" >
  <GridView>
     <!-- Many GridViewColumn that display values --> 

     <GridViewColumn Header="Chart" Width="70" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Name="btnDisplayChart" Content="Chart"
                                        Click="DisplayChart_Click"
                                        Tag="{Binding ID}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       </GridViewColumn>
  </GridView>
</Listview>
```

CurrentPrices is an asynchronous ObservableCollection and a separate thread updates the other columns every 200ms. Now when I click the button as defined above nothing appears to happen (like I didn't click the button), but if I increase the sleeping time of the other thread (i.e. 2000ms) the code behind correctly processes the event.

Could you please point me to the right direction?

Here is the code that update the collection

```
private void getRemotePrices(){
            while(update)
            {
                lock (boccaciccio)
                {
                    MarketPrices marketprices = bf.GetMarketPrices(market.ID);
                    market.UpdateMarketPrices(marketprices);

                    lastPrices.Clear();
                    foreach (var runnerprice in market.ADATA)
                    {
                        lastPrices.Add(runnerprice);
                    }
                    notifyObservers(lastPrices); //updates every subscriber
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you update the collection, by adding new items or by clearing and loading the entire collection ? The problem is your timer and my guess here is that while you press on an item, the collection changes and your pressed item is changed. I think you need a better approach on this. Executing a timer every 0.2 seconds is CPU killer.

Comment: @alexandru yes mate, I clear the collection and I reload it, since the properties change even faster than the refresh time. And the problem is excactly that while I press the button the collection is refreshed

Comment: Instead of reloading the entire collection, you should keep the same collection and update the prices (on some properties) and let the data binding refresh the data on the GUI, not the way you're currently doing it. You have a design problem here and sooner or later will create a lot of problems in your application. You should rethink your approach.

Comment: @alexandru it's exactly what I did, thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking a button includes mouse down and then mouse up activities. Both activities should be done when the mouse above the same button instance.
When you refresh the items in the GridView too quickly, your mouse down activity happens on one button instance, then the list refreshed and the button instance under your mouse is replaced by other button instance, so mouse up activity done on other button instance.

It the same as if you press mouse button down while the mouse on one button, then move the mouse to other button and then releasing the mouse button. No click event will be fired.

You can change the click event to mouse down or mouse up event and ensure firing , but I don't sure it would be the right solution from the design point of view. If you need design suggestions you should supply more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is refreshing the list. The update is faster than you can click. You shouldn't clear the list, but sync it.